# Azure cloud function not able to access dependencies

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I have been trying to get a function to use a model identify whats in an image. 
I've gotten this to run locally fine. 
Unfortunatly when i publish this it does not work.

I get the following issue:

```
Exception: ImportError: libgthread-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Stack:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 240, in _handle__function_load_request
    func_request.metadata.entry_point)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure_functions_worker/loader.py", line 66, in load_function
    mod = importlib.import_module(fullmodname)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/site/wwwroot/MyHttpTrigger/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    import  cv2
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .cv2 import *
```

I have tried to use the docker method of uploading and the built in method of uploading and both give the same issue.

Has anyone seen this issue and how have you solved it.

Docker and Python are both new to me aswell so please explain.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's complaining it can't find the cv2 library.  I would recommend using the new remote build feature that's currently opt-in.  It's much easier than fighting with the docker approach.  If publishing from the CLI it's:

`func azure functionapp publish <function-name> --build remote`

Should upload the requirements.txt file and build and resolve dependencies in the function environment directly.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python#publishing-to-azure

Comment: unforutantly that yields the exact same result.

Comment: What’s the library you are using? It’s possible it has some OS level dependencies.  I can try to repro if you have any details you can share

Comment: So in making the function app on a windows 10 machine with python 3.6 , i've tried a diffrent machine and diffrent versions all producing the same issue the package is open-cv that appears to be causing the issue. I amn't sure i follow by what library am i using? i've used azures built in libary as far as i can tell? Any other questions please ask me as i've seen this same issue reported a few times and I really want to solve it. Thaks.

Comment: Looks like the image we use may require something like this added to the image. I’m not sure if a way around without running as a custom container in the premium plan for now, but worth creating an issue in GitHub to track adding this https://www.kaggle.com/c/inclusive-images-challenge/discussion/70226 — http://github.com/azure/azure-Functions-Python-worker